# swift: could not read (local) plist file to Dictionary in a playground

Tags: ios, swift, plist

1.I creat a new playground,and add my 2.plist to the playground's package content folder.
2.I tried:

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("2", ofType:"plist"){
println(path)// "/var/folders/....../2.plist"

myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
println(myDict)// nil

let url:NSURL! = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("2", withExtension:"plist")
myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: url)
println(myDict) //nil

var str = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)! 
// ??? here display the String content of 2.plist
} else {
println("exist")
}
```

3.I have tried many ways, but could not read the plist to dictionary.Why???

Many thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are adding your Plist file wrongly so follow this step:

**File Inspector**

In the XCode menu just select **View -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector**:

[image]

You’ll see a panel on the right hand side. The **Playground Settings** section will have your path to the **Resource** folder. Just click the little arrow, and open up the Resource folder!

[image]

Now just add your plist file in the Resources folder, and code away!

Here you can see you code is working perfectly after following this steps.

[image]

Here is my plist format for more information:

[image]

Reference from [here](http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-6-add-image-assets-to-playground/)
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some thing wrong with the 2.plist.
The content of 2.plist could not be read with NSDictionary,but with NSArray.

Comment: It is probably an array of dictionaries