# Read plist in swift 3 playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-playground

I have followed loads of questions here but nothing seems to work.

I am using `Swift3` in a `Playground`. Running on El Capitan and Xcode 8.1.
I have a `plist` with the root as a `Dictionary` containing one Int value and two 2D Arrays of Ints.

[plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlLiP.png)

Every question I follow does not seem to work the closest I have got is for the playground to not return errors but it seems to be constantly running (the spinning icon never stops).

my current code, I believe to be the closest I have achieved.

```
import Foundation 
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "levelList", ofType: "plist") {
    let plistXML = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path)!

    let mydata = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistXML, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:Any]
}
```

other options I have tried from previous stack overflow answers in a similar context.

```
let mydata = Dictionary(fromPropertyList: path, format: "XML") as! [String: Any]
******
let mydata = Dictionary(contentsOf: path) as? [String: Any]
```

The data was added to the resources folder correctly as the linked question gave instructions for.
I have restarted Xcode(and mac) as suggested in the comments. After a while the execution stopped with error "error: Execution was interrupted reason exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x0)"
After another restart the code works. How do would i extract the data into an array in swift since at the moment the playground is showing
["Level 2":["Col": <_NS_array0 0x7fc620d091a0>(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956211/swift-could-not-read-local-plist-file-to-dictionary-in-a-playground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finally get the program working I used.

```
devices = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [AnyObject]
```

The issue with playground continuously running was solved by going to activity monitor and force quitting the process named com.apple.coresimulator which was identified as not responding. After doing this the playground ran instantly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong API, you need to load `Data` rather than something in the file system.

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "levelList", withExtension: "plist"),
   let plistData = try? Data(contentsOf: url ) {
      let mydata = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:Any]
}
```

Comment: Based on the OP's own answer, you seem to be casting incorrectly. The OP's original code was casting to a dictionary, just like this answer. But the OP's own answer indicates the problem was due to the fact that the plist file contains an array, not a dictionary. And the OP was not using the wrong API to get the data, just a different API than suggested here.

Comment: @rmaddy It's confusing. The screenshot in the question indicates clearly a dictionary as root element.

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice the screenshot. Yes, the root is a dictionary so your code would be correct in that regard. So the OP's own answer makes no sense at all.