# Swift 3 - Get all items from all arrays from plist

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

I'm trying to get a combination of all the items for all the keys in the plist.

With the code below I am getting the values for keys separately and I can get their items however when user clicks on the cell where index = 0 I want to show all the items

This is the plist

```
func loadPlist()->[[String:String]] {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myText", ofType: "plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    var keyPath = ""


    if muscleIndex == 0{
        //Show values from all keys here
    }
    else if muscleIndex == 1{
        keyPath = "abs"
    }
    else if muscleIndex == 2{
        keyPath = "arms"
    }
    else if muscleIndex == 3{
      keyPath = "back"
    }
    else if muscleIndex == 4{
        keyPath = "chest"
    }
    else if muscleIndex == 5{
        keyPath = "shoulders"
    }
    else if muscleIndex == 6{
        keyPath = "legs"
    }


    let levelArray:AnyObject = dict.object(forKey: keyPath)! as AnyObject
    let nsArray:NSArray = (levelArray as? NSArray)!


    return nsArray as! [[String : String]]
}
```

[image]

Comment: What about using let allKeyPaths = [String](), each time you do allKeyPath.append("arms") (etc.), in case of 0, do a for loop adding all the keyPaths. Use a NSMutableArray, and for each string (ie a keyPath) in `allKeyPaths`, append the content of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do, keeping most part of your logic:
Use an array of "keypaths"
Iterate then for all keyPath, appending the content of each "subarray" to the final array.

[Use suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41075571/1801544) to read from plist because from Swift3+ we tend to avoid using `NSDictionary`/`NSArray` (all `NS` stuff) whenever possible.

```
var keyPaths = [String]()

if muscleIndex == 0 {
    keyPaths.append("abs")
    keyPaths.append("arms")
    ... (you can append all of them in one line too)
}
else if muscleIndex == 1 {
    keyPaths.append("abs")
}
else if ...


var returnArray = [[String:String]]()
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "plistTest", ofType: "plist")
{

    let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    if let plistData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: fileURL)
    {
        let topLevel = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:Any]
        for aKeyPath in keyPaths {
            let subArray = topLevel[aKeyPath] as! [[String:String]]
            returnArray.append(contentsOf: subArray)
        }
    }
}
return returnArray
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, can I just ask, in the for loop you mentioned for aKeyPath in keys, where is keys from?

Comment: I meant keyPaths, sorry

Comment: thank you so much, I must say i have been searching the internet for over 3 weeks for this nice perfect solution, I wish I found you earlier